# Keeping track of WebRTC stats on Android

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

How I can use [chrome://webrtc-internals](https://_) for mobile Chrome (Android)? Yes, I can open it in a separate tab on the same phone, and can even switch between the tow tabs: the one that runs my webRTC client and the one that collects the stats. But this means that I cannot follow this in real time, and the 6″ screen is too small… And I can go to [chrome://inspect/#devices](https://_) on the connected PC, but it does not help me see the WebRTC stats of the device.

Comment: is there a way to do `android-webrtc` so its natively java or kotlin and not javascript as we do in `react-native-webrtc` am curious, `android-webrtc` kind tempting to check it

Comment: The react-native implementation is built on top of `android-webrtc`, so it definitely is different from what we have in the browser. My concern is about comparing behavior of different devices with different versions of Android and Chrome installed, so, on the face of it, this approach does not help.